# BotFramework Error on SendAsync and CreateReply

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I tried solution at [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163544/bot-dialog-not-waiting) and it successfully posted to the bot. However I am also using [offline-directline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-directline) to run my bot locally. It seems that both the `Conversation.SendAsync` mentioned in the answer and the suggested `message.CreateReply()` (from the [blog](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/07/12/how-to-properly-send-a-greeting-message-and-common-issues-from-customers/)) throw an `ArgumentNullException`.
Is this an error on post? Do I need to create a new Activity?

Comment: `throw an ArgumentNullException` Do you check the exception details or debug the code to find which object or property is null?

Comment: This. The `CreateReply` created a new `Activity` type and didn't say which property was not being set, I manually created the response and found the culprit.